# Expectation of Sample Variance

Tags: variance, sampling, estimators

This is a question from the book Casella and Berger: [image]

where $ES$ actually means $\mathbb{E}(S)$ (expectation of S) 
So, I manage to use the Jensen Inequality to prove that $\mathbb{E}(S) \leq \sigma$, and for the last proof I want to use contradiction:

So far I got:

Suppose $\sigma^{2} > 0$ and $\mathbb{E}(S)=\sigma$

Then, by hypothesis we can write: $[\mathbb{E}(S)]^{2}=\sigma^{2} = \mathbb{E}(S^{2})$

So this actually means that $Var(S) = 0$

If $S$ does not have variance, we can write that: $S = \sigma$

Therefore: $\sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i} - \bar{X})^{2}}{n-1}} = \sigma$

But I don't know how to continue and get a contradiction.

Comment: Note that $\text{Var}(S) \geq 0$ and $\text{Var}(S)=E(S^2)-E(S)^2$. Go from there. This is covered in a couple of answers on site already, try a search.

Comment: I don't understand @Glen_b, I already know that $Var (S) = 0$. How can I reach a contradiction starting from that?

Comment: What you say you know, ain't so. $S$ is a random variable; if the original distribution is continuous and has nonzero population variance, sample standard deviations will definitely be positive